# Apply divergence theorem for $\int_R r \times \operatorname{div}(v \otimes v)dV$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, cross-product, divergence-operator, divergence-theorem

I'm trying to show the following integral equality, but I really can't come up with a proof. The context here is the one of an introductive book to continuum mechanics, so everything is smooth and there are no differetiability problems.

> Let $R$ be a control volume in the space, with $v$ a velocity field and $r(x)=x-0$ the position vector. Then $$\int_R r \times \operatorname{div}(v \otimes v)dV = \int_{\partial R}r \times (v\cdot n)vdA$$

Clearly, the divergence theorem must be used. The fact is that I really don't know how to move things so to get something like $\int_R \operatorname{div}(\ldots)dV$, because that cross product is tricky to solve.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to work with components. As suggested, I try to take the divergence of the r.h.s.

$r \times (v \cdot n) v$ has i-th component $\varepsilon_{ijk} x_j v_ln_lv_k$ and hence I take the i-th derivative, since I want to compute its divergence

$$\varepsilon_{ijk}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}  \bigl(x_j v_ln_lv_k \bigr) $$ but after this I really get lost in the computations. How should I move from here?

Comment: Probably $v\otimes v$ is some kind of a dyad here, for normally divergence is a scalar field, and it is non-sensical to calculate a cross product with it. So exactly what kind of a dyad is it, and how is the divergence of a dyad defined?

Comment: Yes, here $v \otimes v$ is a dyad, i.e. a rank 2 tensor, with component i-j given by $v_i v_j$ @JyrkiLahtonen . In particular, the divergence of a tensor $S$ is a vector with i-th component $\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_j}$ (sum over $j$ is implied)

Comment: Hint: There isn't much actual work to be done. From the definition of tensor product in continuum mechanics courses $$(a\otimes b)c = (b\cdot c)a$$ Apply this definition to one of the integrals.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I know to that definition, the fact is that I don't know how to rewrite the l.h.s. so that I can apply divergence thm. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: If you think the lhs side integral is the one to modify, you're making life harder, because the lhs already has a divergence written into it. Apply the formula to the rhs.

Comment: Applying the definiton of dyadic product I get $$\int_{\partial R} r \times (v \otimes v)ndA$$ I still can't apply divergence thm directly, there must be one more step. How can I move? @NinadMunshi

Comment: You can apply it directly from here, what difficulties do you find?

Comment: @NinadMunshi So you see $r \times (v \otimes v)$ directly as a vector, say $S$, and from here you have $$\int_{\partial R} S n dA = \int_{R} div(S) dV$$, right?

Comment: It's not a vector as you correctly noted, but you can still apply divergence theorem. If it confuses you, stick to the index notation definition of the calculations.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Indeed, since it's not a vector...what is it? Do you see it as a tensor?

Comment: It's a matrix? At some point the pre calculation questions have to end and the post calculation questions need to come in. Just do the calculation and edit any difficulties you had into your post. Remember divergence is just a derivative, and derivatives need to obey product rule in some form.

Comment: Again, you're working on the lhs when you should have been trying to take the divergence of the rhs

Comment: @NinadMunshi Am I on the right path? I am sorry to keep asking, but I honestly need some more hints on this